# Why is this php string displaying in the wrong order?

Tags: php, wordpress

This happens all the time and I think it is a simple php error that I'm making and I can't for the life of me find the manual for this!
the php looks like this:

```
echo '<h2 class="term-title">Search Results for '.the_search_query().'</h2>';
```

it turns out like this (when I search for garlic):

```
<br/>
garlic<br/>
<h2>Search Results for</h2>
```

I've tried several variations of the same code:

```
$title='<h2>';
$title .=the_search_query();
$title .='</h2>';
echo $title;
```

The display is the same.  I've tried a  <span> tag instead - always the same output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is really vague. How should it appear and how does it appear. What does the search query do?

Comment: FYI - [`the_search_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query)

Answer (score 5):

Like many (horrible) Wordpress functions, I assume `the_search_query_that_you_searched_for_lol_kthxbye()` performs an `echo`. This `echo` will be evaluated as part of your `echo` statement, thus appearing in the output buffer first.

Use [`get_search_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_search_query) instead or implement your original code like this

```
<h2 class="term-title">Search Results for <?php the_search_query() ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

is your the_search_query() function returning a value or it was directly echoing all values it gets?.

for example:

```
 function the_search_query()
 {
 return $result;
 }
```

or

```
 function the_search_query()
 {
 echo $result;
 }
```

this seems the same.
but directly echoing the function results sometimes get messed up when it comes to displaying the output correctly.

Comment: You should not use obscene expressions.

Comment: [`the_search_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query) is a built-in Wordpress function